# Pointer in Function from a Struct not working

Tags: c, function, struct

let's say i got a struct like this:

```
 typedef struct myInfo {
    WORD myCount;
    WORD data[0];
} myInfo;
```

Well, i would like to use this struct (which is declare extern by the way), in another .c source file, where i've got a function like this:

```
void dynamic_init(struct myInfo dummy){ 

     macroPut(5, dummy.myCount, &dummy.mydata); <- doesn't work
      macroPut(5, dummy.myCount, &externalInitialized.mydata); <- works
}
```

This way i would dynamically use this dynamic_init without worring about the struct name...
But as u could easily see in my snippet above, it works only with the inizialized struct...but if i call the function this way:

```
 dynamic_init(externalInitialized);
```

It won't work.

In other words i've got to do something like this:

```
 dynamic_init( externalInitialized.myCount, externalInitialized.mydata);
```

And i have the result expected.

The main mistery is that is the "mydata" WORD that corrupt everything.
the "myCount" works as expected if i do this way:

```
   dynamic_init( externalInitialized, externalInitialized.mydata);
```

and then:

void dynamic_init(struct externalInitialized dummy, WORD *dynData){

```
  macroPut( 5, dummy.myCount, &dynData); <- works
```

}

I know it's dumb, but it's just to show the exact wrong part.

Thanks!

Comment: What is "another_function"?

Comment: That is a _type definition_ as the word `typedef` implies, It is not a stucture _declaration_, neither do you _define_ a struct. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and define what you have tried, want to achieve and what you actually get.

Comment: Please don't expect us to guess what "doesn't work" could mean.

Comment: Note that `WORD mydata[0];` is a zero-sized array. `&dummy.mydata` wouldt hus yield a pointer beyond the struct. And as Hans asked, what means `"works" and "doesn't work".

Comment: Guys, you r very right, but i've got a ".a" file which has the magic inside, and i can't decompile it. I thought i was missing something, because i'm a C rookie, but it seems it's not my fault, i'm using correctly the argument passing it in the function, now i'm stuck...don't know what to do.

Comment: Not very sure, but looks like you're stuck with pass-by-value in case of the `void dynamic_init(struct myInfo dummy)` case.

Comment: Sure Sourav, it's the passing value  my actual problem. I showed where it works and where not, i would like to pass only that struct in the function, but it works only if i pass the value referred in that struct.

Comment: Even if that is an archive, you should have a header for it with the function declarations - unless that is pre-ANSI (K&R) C. You should follow the given interface. The phrase "doen't work" is far too wide: "My car does not work" - "well, you should pay it better then".

Comment: Okay, this is the header file:
http://www.filedropper.com/datlib . I've reworked the names in the examples.

Comment: Not sure I get a question, but you **really** shouldn't pass flexible-sized structure by value. Pass a pointer instead. Compiler have no idea what actual size would be and will not correctly copy entire `data` array.

Comment: mmm keltar i think you're right, infact if i pass the pointer it works. Why that? happens? If u make an answer i could accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass structure to function, compiler generates code to copy structure contents, so function gets its own copy of parameters that it can freely modify without affecting original. Copying is performed for `sizeof struct` bytes.

Your main problem here is that your structure have [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), so its `sizeof` have very little to do with real size it will occupy.

E.g. structure's in question `sizeof` is 4 (last field is array of 0 elements so it doesn't increas sizeof), but when you allocating memory for structure, you actually allocating much more - and saving 'real' size in structure field. That way, accessing `data` array will actually get elements outside of structure itself (placed right next bytes to it); however, compiler don't know that (and cannot know, as size differs from one structure instance to another). For the same reason you cannot directly place that structure on stack and safely fill data - because that will touch bytes that doesn't belong to it and corrupt other things (technically it can be placed on stack, but you have to manually align it within on-stack array of enough size).

Flexible array member have other limitations, like you cannot make an array of that type of structures (once again - technically you can, but it makes no sense since array indexing relies on `sizeof`).

So, short answer is "don't pass flexible-sized structures by value". Or even think twice before passing structure by value at all - copying isn't free, after all.